# Need to upsample audio from 8k to 16k

Tags: javascript, audio-streaming, web-audio-api, resampling, pcm

I was using below code for downsampling my audio while recording

```
let inputSampleRate; let inputBuffer = [];

function init(x) {
     inputSampleRate = x; 
}

function process(inputFrame) {
     for (let i = 0; i < inputFrame.length; i++) {
        inputBuffer.push((inputFrame[i]) * 32767);
     }

     const PV_SAMPLE_RATE = 16000;
     const PV_FRAME_LENGTH = 512;
 
     while ((inputBuffer.length * PV_SAMPLE_RATE / inputSampleRate) > PV_FRAME_LENGTH) {
        let outputFrame = new Int16Array(PV_FRAME_LENGTH);
        let sum = 0;
        let num = 0;
        let outputIndex = 0;
        let inputIndex = 0;

        while (outputIndex < PV_FRAME_LENGTH) {
            sum = 0;
            num = 0;
            while (inputIndex < Math.min(inputBuffer.length, (outputIndex + 1) * inputSampleRate / PV_SAMPLE_RATE)) {
                sum += inputBuffer[inputIndex];
                num++;
                inputIndex++;
            }
            outputFrame[outputIndex] = sum / num;
            outputIndex++;
        }

        postMessage(outputFrame);

        inputBuffer = inputBuffer.slice(inputIndex);
    } 
}
```

Can anyone please suggest how can I edit this one, so that it can be used to upsample my audio from 8k to 16k?

Answer (score 2):

The traditional way to do upsampling (and downsampling) can be found at [Wikipedia article about upsampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsampling).

If you want something really cheap and dirty, just linearly interpolate between samples.  So if you have samples x0 and x1, the upsampled values are y0=x0, y2=x1, and the new sample y1=(x0+x1)/2.  This isn't great and you might hear artifacts.

Edit:

In your code, you can try something like this:

```
s0 = inputBuffer[inputIndex];
s1 = inputBuffer[inputIndex + 1];
outputFrame[outputIndex] = s0;
outputFrame[outputIndex + 1] = (s0 + s1)/2;
outputFrame[outputIndex + 2] = s1
```

You'll have to keep track of the indices so you don't try to access beyond the length of the arrays.  This is totally untested.

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. I understand what you're saying but can you suggest how I can apply that in the code I've attached, just what changes in the calculation part is needed.

Comment: I  think it would be something like this:

Comment: I tried completing my code, please have a look. "function init(x) {
    inputSampleRate = x;
}

function process(inputFrame) {
    for (let i = 0; i < inputFrame.length; i++) {
        inputBuffer.push((inputFrame[i]) * 32767);
}
const PV_FRAME_LENGTH = 512;
for (let inputIndex = 0; inputIndex<inputBuffer.length - 1; inputIndex++) {
 let outputFrame = new Int16Array(PV_FRAME_LENGTH);
 s0 = inputBuffer[inputIndex];
 s1 = inputBuffer[inputIndex + 1];
 
 let outputIndex = 2*inputIndex;
 
 outputFrame[outputIndex] = s0;
 outputFrame[outputIndex + 1] = (s0 + s1)/2;
}"

Comment: Please create a snippet at jsfiddle.net or codepen.com or whatever.  Then you can share it and then I can look at it and provide more feedback.  Use, perhaps, a sinewave as the input.  The output should like like a sinewave, of course.